# exec redirect messes up output order in bash

Tags: bash, redirect, fifo

I am using `>(...)` to modify my output. It works but the order of the output is getting messed up and I'm not sure why.

In the below code I:

1. output some lines to the normal `STDOUT`
2. save the `STDOUT` and `STDERR`
3. modify the output of `STDOUT` and `STDERR` using exec and `>(..)`
4. send output to the newly modified `STDOUT` and `STDERR`
5. revert to the original `STDOUT` and `STDERR`
6. send output to the original `STDOUT` and `STDERR`

I would expect the output to look like #1, #4, #6 but what I am getting is #1, **#6, #4**.

```
#!/bin/bash

# output text to normal STDOUT
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">'
echo '<html>'
echo "    <head><title>daily backup script: ${now}</title></head>"
echo '    <body style="font-family:monospace; font-size: 10px">'
echo '        <table border="1">'

# save STDOUT and STDERR
exec 6>&1
exec 7>&2

# modify STDOUT
exec 1> >(
    while read line
    do
        echo "            <tr><td>$(date +%Y-%m-%d)</td><td>$(date +%H:%M:%S)</td><td colSPan='5'>${line}</td></tr>" >&6
    done
)

# modify STDERR
exec 2> >(
    while read line
    do
        echo "            <tr style='color: red'><td>$(date +%Y-%m-%d)</td><td>$(date +%H:%M:%S)</td><td colSPan='5'>${line}</td></tr>" >&6
    done
)

# output to new modified STDOUT and STDERR
echo "test"
echo "test again" >&2
date

# revert to original STDOUT and STDERR
exec 1>&6 6>&-
exec 2>&7 7>&-

# output text to normal STDOUT
echo '        </table>'
echo '    </body>'
echo '</html>'
```

I **expect** the output to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head><title>daily backup script: </title></head>
    <body style="font-family:monospace; font-size: 10px">
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:08:01</td><td colSPan='5'>test</td></tr>
            <tr style='color: red'><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:08:01</td><td colSPan='5'>test again</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:08:01</td><td colSPan='5'>Sat Feb 13 20:08:01 EST 2016</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this is the actual output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head><title>daily backup script: </title></head>
    <body style="font-family:monospace; font-size: 10px">
        <table border="1">
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
user@hostname:/path/to/script$             <tr style='color: red'><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:11:29</td><td colSPan='5'>test again</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:11:29</td><td colSPan='5'>test</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2016-02-13</td><td>20:11:29</td><td colSPan='5'>Sat Feb 13 20:11:29 EST 2016</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I did was to create a simpler version of your test case with just a few lines of code. It redirect just stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1.message
exec 6>&1
exec 1> >( while read line ; do echo ${line} >&6 ; done )
echo 2.message
exec 1>&6 6>&-
echo 3.message
```

I guess you would expect to see output messages in this order:

```
1.message
2.message
3.message
```

but... no! I was able to replicate your issue. If you run the few lines of code here above you get:

```
1.message
3.message
2.message
```

The problem of an echo piped to a while-read loop running in a subshell is described [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html#BADREAD0) where they say:

> ...the read **acts as** if it were running in a subshell...

In order to work-around this issue - and produce messages in the order I guess you would expect, I did create a named pipe, redirecting stdout to this named pipe. Then I did fork a "real" subshell and wait for its completion this way:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mypipe=/tmp/$$.tmp
trap "rm -f ${mypipe}" EXIT
mknod ${mypipe} p
echo 1.message
exec 6>&1
cat < ${mypipe} &
exec 1>${mypipe}
echo 2.message
exec 1>&6 6>&-
wait
echo 3.message
```

Which produce:

```
1.message
2.message
3.message
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how incorporate this into what I am trying to do but not having much luck. Basically I am running a command that will echo to both `stdout` and `stderr` streams. I want to modify the output differently depending on which stream the output is going to.